# How to use subquery in delete/update query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.0

I am using a mysql 5.0.77 database using the query:

```
Delete from IPADDRESS
where visitdate Not in (SELECT max(visitdate) FROM IPADDRESS WHERE USERNAME='MGSH0002') 
and USERNAME='MGSH0002'
```

I am getting this error when executed:

> You can't specify target table IPADDRESS for update in from clause

Comment: why was this with java tag? moved to mysql

Answer (score 3):

Certainly not the best solution but for your problem this will do the trick:

```
delete i1 from
  IPADDRESS i1,
  IPADDRESS i2
where
  i1.username = i2.username
  and i1.username = 'MGSH0002'
  and i1.visitdate < i2.visitdate
```

An alternative and much more smarter solution is the following statement:

```
delete i1 from
  IPADDRESS i1,
  (select max(visitdate) visitdate from IPADDRESS where username = 'MGSH0002') temp
where
  i1.username = 'MGSH0002'
  and i1.visitdate < temp.visitdate
```

Comment: thnks this is working i have one more query "Delete from IPADDRESS where visitdate Not in (SELECT visitdate FROM (SELECT visitdate FROM IPADDRESS WHERE USERNAME='MGSH0002' ORDER BY visitdate DESC) where ROWNUM < 4) and USERNAME='MGSH0002'" its working in oracle but not in mysql plz help

Comment: The second solution is certainly much smarter. It probably needs the `group by username` to become `WHERE username = 'MGSH0002'` in the `temp` subquery but it's better than the first. And faster if there is an index on `(username, visitdate)`

Comment: Thx ypercube! I have edited my second solution and now we have a smart one, I think.

Comment: @manorma: Try this one to delete all but the 3 newest entries in MySQL:
`delete i1 from IPADDRESS i1, (select visitdate from IPADDRESS where username = 'MGSH0002' order by visitdate desc limit 2,1) temp 
where i1.username = 'MGSH0002' and i1.visitdate < temp.visitdate`

Btw: It would be nice if you would mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, unfortunately MySql doesn't allow this.

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in
>   a subquery.

From:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: thanku 4 ur ans but is there any alternate way to do the same